# Динамическое количество форм

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, form

Пользователь при заполнении формы может задать нужное количество человек (например: 2 взрослых, 3 детей) на странице появляется 5 форм:

```
Взрослые:
   Взрослый1:
     (input)Фамилия
     (input)Имя
   Взрослый2:
     (input)Фамилия
     (input)Имя
Дети:
   Ребенок1:
     (input)Фамилия
     (input)Имя
   Ребенок2:
     (input)Фамилия
     (input)Имя
   Ребенок3:
     (input)Фамилия
     (input)Имя
```

Дальше все эти данные должны передаваться ajax-ом на сервер, вопрос как организовать идентификацию каждой формы, как скомпоновать данные для ajax что бы передать на сервер?

Comment: обэект, массив, неужели так сложно?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, для новичка, до этого момента не сталкивавшегося с таким вопросом, сложно! Вот если бы Вы оставили развернутый ответ, с примером, было бы гораздо проще! А так комент ради комента

Answer (score 1):

Вы задаёте неправильный вопрос. Вам нужна одна форма, а input`ы нужно обрабатывать как массивы. Например,

```
<input name="parent_name[]">
```

Comment: Как добавить data для ajax на основе вашего примера?

Comment: Например, вот так http://ruseller.com/jquery?id=8